Git latest version installed using homebrew not getting used in mac. Instead the Xcode one gets used, despite adding to the path variables
I have to update git to the latest version. I updated the brew version of git to latest one and used the unlink command. I have the xcode version installed as well. I have tried setting up the path variables but am not able to update the order of path variables to pick up
I did that using the "brew upgrade git"
brew upgrade git
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: git 2.47.0 already installed


I ended the terminal and opened a new one. Now when I check the version, I am getting
git --version
git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)


I checked the locations of git using which, and got the below results
which -a git
/usr/bin/git
/opt/homebrew/bin/git
/usr/bin/git


When I check the PATH using echo, I am getting "/usr/bin/git" before "/opt/homebrew/bin/git"
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:

I want to use the git in homebrew, but am not able to do that. I tried updating the order of the locations taking reference from this article. https://codewithsusan.com/notes/path-variable-mac
I found the directories to be located in "sudo nano ~/.bashrc"
But after updating, ending the terminal and opening again I still get the paths as
tr ':' '\n' <<< $PATH

/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin


I am not able to understand what I am missing, so that git command picks up the brew installed one.

When I check the PATH using echo, I am getting "/usr/bin/git" before "/opt/homebrew/bin/git" Well isn't that exactly the cause of the problem?

I found the directories to be located in "sudo nano ~/.bashrc" I very strongly doubt that in this day and age you are using bash — and so it doesn't matter what's in .bashrc, as it is never consulted.

OK, let's debug this. We first need to ask a set of questions.

What shell are you running? Why? This defines how $PATH is set.
As of MacOSX Catalina (2019), the default shell is zsh, not bash
Where is the path being set...

Determine Shell
> echo $SHELL
> /bin/zsh

The above is what I would expect to see. Can you confirm this?
Determine the git being used?
On macOS, type is preferred over which - it provides more detailed information about how the shell interprets a command. type can identify whether a command is an alias, a shell function, a built-in, or an external executable. It shows how the shell will interpret the command. My system returns (I set it to do this):
> type git                                                         
git is an alias for noglob git
git is /usr/bin/git
git is /opt/homebrew/bin/git
> git --version
git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)

Check the path
Let's modify the $PATH to see if we can fix this.
> export $PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/git:$PATH

> type git                                                         
git is an alias for noglob git
git is /opt/homebrew/bin/git
git is /usr/bin/git
> git --version
git version 2.47.0

Resolution
If your system is running zsh, i.e. $SHELL returns zsh then you need to look in:

~/.zshrc: The most common file for user-specific Zsh configuration. The $PATH is often modified here.
~/.zprofile: This file is executed at the start of a Zsh login shell. $PATH can also be modified here, though typically a less likely culprit.

now if $SHELL returns bash, then you need to look in:

~/.bash_profile: This file is executed for login shells. It is a common place to set or modify the $PATH.
~/.bashrc: Executed for interactive non-login shells. It's often used to customize the shell environment.
~/.profile: This file is used if ~/.bash_profile is not present. It can also be used to set or modify $PATH for login shells.
~/.bash_login: Executed for login shells if ~/.bash_profile is not found. It's less commonly used but can still modify the $PATH.

Wrap-up
My gut feeling is that once you determine your shell, you can debug this.
Citations

Zsh Startup Files
--  https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html

Bash Startup Files
--  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html


